# Lowercase subcaption labels when using the caption and subcaption packages

Tags: captions, subcaption

I am using the [`caption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption?lang=en) and [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs?lang=en) packages to create subtables and to caption them. I use the [`caption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption?lang=en) package to change caption style for all floats. I used the [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs?lang=en) package to create subtables. I use the [`booktabs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs?lang=en) package to help make my table look good. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
%  \centering
  \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{First table}\label{tab:mytable:first}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \toprule
      A & B\\
      \midrule
      1 & 2\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}

  \vspace*{16pt}
  
  \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
    \caption{Second table}\label{tab:mytable:second}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \toprule
      C & D\\
      \midrule
      3 & 4\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
  \caption{My caption referring to \subref{tab:mytable:first}~first table
and \subref{tab:mytable:second}~second table.}\label{tab:mytable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

... which gives this output:

[image: output]

How do I make the subtable labels lowercase ((a) instead of (A), (b) instead of (B), ...) without changing any other styles, placement, etc?

If possible, I would like this formatting to occur locally -- either local to tables in my thesis or local to this *particular* table in my thesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between `\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}` and `\caption...`, add the line

```
\renewcommand\captionlabelfont{}
```

The change is local to the particular table. Notice the difference between the first subtable (changed) and the second one (unchanged).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
%  \centering
  \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
    \renewcommand\captionlabelfont{}% <<< HERE <<< HERE <<< HERE
    \centering
    \caption{First table}\label{tab:mytable:first}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \toprule
      A & B\\
      \midrule
      1 & 2\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}

  \vspace*{16pt}
  
  \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
    \tracingmacros=2
    \caption{Second table}\label{tab:mytable:second}
    \tracingmacros=0
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \toprule
      C & D\\
      \midrule
      3 & 4\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
  \caption{My caption referring to \subref{tab:mytable:first}~first table
and \subref{tab:mytable:second}~second table.}\label{tab:mytable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use in your preamble

```
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens, labelfont=up]{subcaption}
```

[image]